# How to change user agent on all http requests made from my machine with Squid intercepting proxy?

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy, http

I'd like to change the user agent on *all* HTTP requests made from this machine. It's easy enough to change the user agent in each browser, but other apps also make http requests. It's vital I catch them all. In particular, there's one app (Steam) that has no option to change the user agent.

Thus, I want to run an intercepting proxy that changes the user agent on all http requests made from my computer.

I wrote this `squid.conf`

```
# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128
http_port 3127 intercept

# i don't care for caching. -Matt
cache deny all

request_header_access User-Agent deny ALL
```

It works when I point browsers at it. But how can I get Squid to intercept all http requests made by my machine? I don't understand how to make it capture stuff. Iptables? Firewalld?

Comment: Update 2015: I never figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

Install nginx as a transparent proxy. here's an example configuration stanza to show how to change user-agent:

```
http {
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass              http://$host$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header        "User-Agent" "custom agent";
            proxy_connect_timeout   60;
            proxy_send_timeout      60;
            proxy_read_timeout      60;
        }
    }
}
```

Please check out the document [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a transparent proxy that rewrites the request headers on the fly.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: there is no need for the proxy to be transparent, just setting most of applications to use it should be enough.

Comment: Hi. "Set up a transparent proxy that rewrites the request headers on the fly" isn't a useful answer when the question was "How do I set up a transparent proxy that rewrites the request headers on the fly?"

Comment: I shoved "squid transparent proxy" into Google and got [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html) back. And "squid rewrite headers" found [this](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation).

Answer (score 2):

for squid3 transparent proxy write..

```
http_port 3127  transparent
```

force traffic from 80 to your port 3127

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination Server.ip.Address : 3127
```

to make sure it takes that route close/block port 80
all traffic coming from lan network can't access port 80.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your proxy to operate in "[transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy)" or more correctly "Intercepting" mode. Interception is being done on different OSI level with another tools, usually firewalls. The link above will share quite a handful of details to you, don't hesitate.